# Convert SP2013 from Classic to Claims

Tags: 2013, powershell, migration, claims-based-auth, warning

We migrated from SP2010 Classic to SP2013 Classic after which we migrated to SP2013 Claims using the below PS Script:

```
Convert-SPWebApplication -Identity "WebAppURL:PortNumber" -From Legacy -To Claims -RetainPermissions -Force
```

This script completed with the below warning:

> WARNING: The conversion of web application and most of the users to
>   Claims mode  is completed. However, one or more users could not be
>   converted to Claims mode. Refer to the ULS logs for the details. For
>   the troubleshooting tips refer  to the
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=236943 article.

On checking few site collections using the below PS Script,

```
Get-SPUser -Web "SiteCollectionURL"
```

I found that few users were not migrated to claims and on checking the Logs,i found the below:

> 09/01/2016 06:54:26.18    PowerShell.exe (0x3E78)
>     0x3EFC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication
>     amb7u   High        SPWebApplication
>   'f85699f3-429f-47b5-b7eb-0700343d2855', SPContentDatabase
>   'd229ffdf-20b0-44dd-8ca7-d30f38dd021b', SPSite
>   '3043b114-3283-4ca3-b62a-34174e71b606': Could not get migration data
>   for user. Check migrator for further logs. Entity Old Name:
>   'Domain\UserName', Old Key
>   'S-1-5-21-3868811463-4218362078-540856563-3403', New Name: '', New Key
>   ''    5f8a2040-478e-41d2-9e74-47e1d7032bec
>
> 09/01/2016 06:54:26.18    PowerShell.exe (0x3E78)
>     0x3EFC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication
>     amb7z   Unexpected  SPWebApplication
>   'f85699f3-429f-47b5-b7eb-0700343d2855', SPContentDatabase
>   'd229ffdf-20b0-44dd-8ca7-d30f38dd021b', SPSite
>   '3043b114-3283-4ca3-b62a-34174e71b606', SPUser '3465': Could not get
>   migration data for entity so SKIPPING. Check migrator for further
>   logs. Entity Old Name: 'Domain\UserName', Old Key
>   'S-1-5-21-3868811463-4218362078-540856563-3403', New Name: '', New Key
>   ''    5f8a2040-478e-41d2-9e74-47e1d7032bec
>
> 09/01/2016 06:54:26.18    PowerShell.exe (0x3E78)
>     0x3EFC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication
>     amb7y   High        SPWebApplication
>   'f85699f3-429f-47b5-b7eb-0700343d2855', SPContentDatabase
>   'd229ffdf-20b0-44dd-8ca7-d30f38dd021b', SPSite
>   '3043b114-3283-4ca3-b62a-34174e71b606', SPUser '7683': Starting
>   migration of user.    5f8a2040-478e-41d2-9e74-47e1d7032bec 09/01/2016
>   06:54:26.18   PowerShell.exe (0x3E78)
>     0x3EFC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication
>     amb74   High        SPWebApplication
>   'f85699f3-429f-47b5-b7eb-0700343d2855', SPContentDatabase
>   'd229ffdf-20b0-44dd-8ca7-d30f38dd021b', SPSite
>   '3043b114-3283-4ca3-b62a-34174e71b606', SPUser '7683': Ended migration
>   of user.  5f8a2040-478e-41d2-9e74-47e1d7032bec
>
> 09/01/2016 06:54:26.18    PowerShell.exe (0x3E78)
>     0x3EFC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication
>     amb7y   High        SPWebApplication
>   'f85699f3-429f-47b5-b7eb-0700343d2855', SPContentDatabase
>   'd229ffdf-20b0-44dd-8ca7-d30f38dd021b', SPSite
>   '3043b114-3283-4ca3-b62a-34174e71b606', SPUser '3594': Starting
>   migration of user.    5f8a2040-478e-41d2-9e74-47e1d7032bec
>
> 09/01/2016 06:54:26.26    PowerShell.exe (0x3E78)
>     0x3EFC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication
>     d01o    Medium      ConvertWindowsSidToClaim() encountered error: Some or
>   all identity references could not be
>   translated.   5f8a2040-478e-41d2-9e74-47e1d7032bec
>
> 09/01/2016 06:54:26.26    PowerShell.exe (0x3E78)
>     0x3EFC  SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication
>     af32m   Unexpected  Could not convert user with with sid
>   'S-1-5-21-3868811463-4218362078-540856563-1191306'.   5f8a2040-478e-41d2-9e74-47e1d7032bec

What would be the reason for these users not migrating to Claims? How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint also tries to convert accounts, which are disabled or deleted from ActiveDirectory. Those accounts cannot be converted and produce this error message in ULS-Log. This is normal and cannot be avoided or solved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/67122)

Comment: Hi Paul. My Post is an answer to George's question. I edited my Post above to improve it's quality. Thanks for your tip!

Comment: @MHeld I have around 7000 non-migrated users and most of these users exist in AD.I'm doing this migration in Azure and our user profile sync is not running yet,would this has caused any issues?

Comment: Please tell me more about your structure? Do you move to Azure VMs with SharePoint installed? Do you have a separate AD there or are you connected to your OnPremise AD? ...

Answer (score 0):

if your SharePoint 2013 farm is at **April 2014 CU** level or **MS14-022 Security updates** installed in the farm then this is expected behavior as both updates introduced a bug.

You have to apply the **June 2014 CU** or Higher to the farm. 
[SharePoint 2013 April 2014 CU Claims Conversion Bug](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/05/sharepoint-2013-april-2014-cu-claims-%20conversion-bug/)

Comment: Our farm is in March 2016 CU. Also I'm not sure where to start the troubleshooting. I tried adding few users who were not migrated to claims into SharePoint sites permissions but their names got resolved so users who were not migrated exist in AD.

Comment: Please Note: we migrated from On Prem SP2010 to Azure SP2013.For UPS,we migrated only the profile and social DBs and user profile synchorization is not running yet.